# Using ManagementObjectCollection to get connected and in use devices

Tags: c#, usb

I see many examples of the `ManagementObjectCollection` to get a list of usb devices. But is there a way to know if they are connected?

If the device is unplugged, it still shows up in the list. I see a huge list of properties some with encouraging names but none give that info.